# Shoutcast Stream Played on Android Phones : Low Quality

Tags: android-mediaplayer, shoutcast

I have a mediaplayer service inside my app  . It can play Shoutcast Streams. I am selling my app to different customers who have different quality and formats of broadcast.

My own radio can be played without a problem which has the following properties:

```
Server Status:  Stream is currently up but requires registration in the SHOUTcast Directory.
Listeners are allowed and the stream will act like it is private until resolved.
Stream Status:  Stream is up at 96 kbps with 4 of 500 listeners
Listener Peak:  26
Average Listen Time:    27 minutes 2 seconds
Stream Name:    **** Fm
Content Type:   audio/mpeg
Stream Genre(s):    Music
```

However, today I experienced a very interesting issue . One of my customers said the quality of the sound coming from the main speaker is too bad. I checked it on my phone and it really was bad. Interestingly , when you plug in a headset, the quality turns out to be how it should normally be. One more interesting thing is that the stream is played without a problem on tablets' speakers.

The customer's Shoutcast Server has the following properties:

```
Server Status:  Stream is currently up and private
Stream Status:  Stream is up at 96 kbps with 0 of 300 listeners
Stream Name:    
Content Type:   audio/mpeg
Stream Genre(s):    Misc
```

What could be the source of the problem ? Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: I would think 96 kbps is considered low quality...

Comment: Well , my own radio's bitrate is 96kpbs and it seems to be fine .